# Timing in the Edit-Suggestion/Improve cycle

Tags: support, community-wiki, suggested-edits

I have a quick question as to how the timing works in the new edit suggestion feature.

If a user suggests an edit, which I then improve on, then both edits go in to the edit history; as far as I can tell then doing an improvement is functionally the same as doing "approve" followed by doing my own edit.  My question is: what is the time stamp on the *first* edit: is it the time of the *suggestion* or the time of the *improvement*?  My reason for asking is to do with what counts towards making a question CW.

In short: if I'm worried about questions prematurely becoming CW, I would think that my best strategy would be to *reject* the edit and then edit it myself.  Now, this isn't so nice to the person who originally suggested the edit since they don't get their 2 reputation points and they don't get their name in the edit history, so I would like to be told that as far as making a post CW is concerned then "edit - improve" and "edit - accept - re-edit (quickly)" and "edit - reject - edit" have the same effect so that I don't have to balance being nice to the editor with being nice to the original poster.

So, what *is* the current situation with regards to this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the submitted edit *has* to be visible as is, because otherwise the original editor has something they neither wrote nor approved attributed to them.  One could go down the route of having a "compound" edit, which is made up of both the original edit and the improvement edit, but this seems to add a fair bit of complexity.

I think you shouldn't be too worried about the 10 edit limit because it is rarely breached.  I wonder if it has ever happened on tex.sx?  If there is a significant change in the distribution of edits per post as a result of this, perhaps the limits should be increased?

Comment: 10 edits is only the limit for author edits. When it comes to other users editing a post, it only takes 5 separate users to convert a post to Community Wiki. With the improve function attributing to two separate users, that does actually significantly push the post towards the CW barrier.

Comment: In the "reject - re-edit" version of the cycle then the submitted edit isn't visible and there's nothing attributed to the original editor (the reviewer's name goes on the edit).  But I agree that it's not an ideal situation to have this.  I don't think that we have yet reached the 10 edits on tex.SX, but it feels as though this feature potentially brings it a whole lot nearer.

Comment: @Grace: Ah!  I thought that other editors counted towards the 10 edit limit.  Thanks for the correction - I should probably change this answer now.