# Can "Improve" edits not count towards the CW count?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, suggested-edits, community-wiki

This is sort of a continuation of [Timing in the Edit-Suggestion/Improve cycle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/80963/138421).  That was a Request-for-Clarification (which is still open, I might add) about how the Edit/Improve feature counts towards making a post CW.  To save on your clicks, the basic issue is that if someone makes an edit suggestion which is then *improved* upon, then that counts for edits by two extra people in the count towards making a post CW.  (At least, no-one has told me that it *doesn't* do that on the post mentioned above.)

We now have the [new "de-CW" feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2974/is-there-a-way-to-remove-community-wiki-status/83373#83373), but I feel that this doesn't address that issue, though it can mitigate the harmful effects of it.  Being able to retroactively de-CW such a question helps a little, but doesn't actually solve this issue.  Someone has to keep track of whether or not the question has been made CW - and the only one with the incentive to do so is the questioner who is probably not a very experienced SE user (since they asked a question that needed lots of editing!) - and it has to be flagged, and then a moderator has to take action.  Moreover, that action goes *beyond* simply reversing the CW effect but also protects it from further CW-ification.

What I would like to see here is that when the "Improve" button is hit then only one edit counts towards the CW count.  So that's my feature request.

Comment: Didn't know about the remove wiki option.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We've gone a few steps further here and **removed all of the triggers that automatically convert a post to community wiki**. Now, no edits, be they improvements or otherwise, will cause this to happen.

Instead, flags are raised when a post reaches certain thresholds. In the case of multiple editors, we've raised the threshold to 10. Improving does still count as two edits and so it still counts as two separate editors. However, in that there's no more automated punitive action taken, I think it is fair to continue to count it as two editors for the purpose of the flag. Hitting 10 is still a pretty high bar, and it may be worth early notice if something has a lot of suggested edits that had even more people improving them - that's about the same in execution as that many people just straight up making those edits, in practice.

Comment: To be clear, then, the flags go in the usual flagging system (for mods and other high-rep users to see) and then mods (but not high-rep users) can decide to hit it with the wiki-hammer or not.  I'm happy with that solution.

Comment: @Andrew Just moderators, not high rep users. And ideally community wiki shouldn't even be a thing to think about - in most cases you might not have to do anything, but the things you would have to do would be more things like contacting users or cleaning up junk answers.