# Why do edits need two approvals, even from high rep users?

Tags: bug, edits, suggested-edits

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Why multiple approvers for proposed edits](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/78799/why-multiple-approvers-for-proposed-edits)

I have about a zillion rep on SO. I can edit pretty much anything anywhere without needing approval...with one exception. If a low-rep user makes an edit to a post (for example, to improve formatting), I can "approve" that edit but the edit still doesn't take effect until *another* user also approves it. If I have enough rep that I could have simply made the edit myself in the first place (without requiring approval), why does the edit need a second vote to take effect?

Comment: Possible duplicates / related questions: [Instant approval of revisions for users with edit privileges](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/85758/155585), [Editing questions does not need a second opinion, but approving an edit does](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/84727/155585), [Why multiple approvers for proposed edits](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/78799/155585).

Comment: [This answer by Jeff](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/77674/abridged-too-far/77683#77683) explains it.

Comment: Yup. I voted to close this question as a dupe.

Answer (score 2):

If you are sure about the your edit alone is enough, use "Improve" button and don't touch the content of post but Save it, Community User will approve it in one shot.

**Edit**: Above method does not work anymore. Now, "Improve" button need real changes.

Comment: I'll try that next time this happens. Who is the edit attributed to when this technique is used?

Comment: Only Community user there, @Greg, for eg., http://stackoverflow.com/suggested-edits/27046

Comment: @Greg: The edit is attributed to the user who made the original edit; Community gets the credit for the approval.

Comment: @Gabe, @YOU: Phew!!! Is this _by design_?? You can approve the edit _alone_, and noone can even see it was you??? @YOU: Are you sure that suggested edit went this "workaround-single-accept" way? (Sorry for all the `!??`, I'm stymied.) See also: [Can “Improve” edits not count towards the CW count?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/83408/155585)

Comment: This will add two edits to the question, pushing it further towards CW.  The first will be attributed to the low rep user, the second to the high rep user.  The _approvals_ will be by the community user.

Comment: @Andrew, that's NOT correct, see the revisions - http://stackoverflow.com/posts/5372515/revisions - there is no two edits.

Comment: @YOU: It's not?  Then I apologise for the noise (and I've taken back the downvote).  Clearly extrapolating behaviour is not reliable here!

Comment: @Andrew, yeah, its not, SO ignore the edit if there is no changes. But I am agree that it is not reliable, looks abusable, but people don't abuse, because they know its hard to earn 2000+ reps.

Comment: @YOU: The problem (IMHO) is not about **ab** use, but just about **use**!  I would have been afraid to do this because I would have thought that it added two edits.

Comment: @Andrew, I see. Just for note, why I said it is abusable is, Anonymous user could destroy or sugest something bad, and 2000+ user could use "Improve" button, and then there is "Anonymous User" and "Community User" in the revisions list. Other users wouldn't notice who did that.